# Looping through an array with objects returns nothing in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

> var channelsData = [];

//let's assume i have here 3 objects from api calls here

How I can loop through this and get the objects.I tried with

> for

loop and

> forEach

but still got nothing and if i try to get channelsData.length , i get 0.

If i try to console.log channelsData i get this [in the console][1]

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkMLS.png
>   Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var channels = ["andreiknight", "freecodecamp","creativemonkeyz"];
  var channelsData = [];

  var channelsData = [];

  channels.forEach(function(channel) {
    $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + channel + "", function(data){
      //console.log(data);
      channelsData.push(data);
  });
});
  channelsData.forEach(function(channel){
    console.log(channel); // returns nothing in the console
  })



});
```

Comment: post your js code

Comment: Probably got something to do with [**this problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: **Washington Guedes** it's not working, so i am having a call from an api and i push the data to channelsData .

Comment: Can you please post your specific code? Just typing 'for' is unhelpful. We can all guess as to what your problem is but it would be impossible to know for sure without seeing the actual code.

Comment: We need to see your code. It is hard to guess, but probably an asynchronows issue.

Comment: sure wait ` $(document).ready(function() {
  var channels = ["andreiknight", "freecodecamp","creativemonkeyz"];
  var channelsData = [];
  
  channels.forEach(function(channel) {
    $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + channel + "", function(data){
    channelsData.push(data);
  });
});
  channelsData.each(function(channel){
    console.log(channel);
  })
  
  
  
}); `

Comment: use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44504730/edit) button under your question to edit your code into your question. Do not try posting it in comments as there is not enough room and is not readable

Comment: I did it. -----

Comment: `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous call. It means your javascript code will not wait it, because it can take too long to return your data.

Comment: Said that, your `channelsData.forEach` code must be inside the callback of `$.getJSON`

Comment: Thanks , i got it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes thank you, thanks all for helping.